# How to view a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, temp-tables, sqlitestudio

I am using SQLite Studio. When I create a table I can see and add data to it. I cannot see a *temporary* table. My code:

```
create temporary table Books2
    (
    Title    varchar(32)    primary key,
    year     integer        not null,
    des      varchar(750)   null
    );

insert into Books2
values
    (
    'CLRS',
    '2000',
    'A book in Algorithms'
    );
```

How can I access and see the data of `Books2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary table that you create is stored in [a different database named `temp`](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temp_databases) which is also temporary and will be deleted when the current connection will be closed.
The contents of this temporary database are not visible (as far as I know) in SQLite Studio.

To access the temporary table use an ordinary query and to avoid naming conflicts use the prefix `temp` before the table's name:

```
SELECT * FROM temp.Books2;
```

The prefix `main` can be used for the names of the tables of the current database, if needed.